# Making REST API calls from Salesforce to Marketo

Tags: api, rest, marketo

I am new to both making API calls and coding in Apex and feel way over my head.

How can I make a call to the Marketo REST API through Salesforce? Is this possible through Apex?

For example, hypothetically, say I didn't want to use the automatic sync of Marketo and Salesforce for some reason. Would it be possible to use Apex to push a lead to Marketo manually using something similar to this:

1. When a new lead is created, trigger Apex class "syncLead"
2. syncLead requests token and logs in to Marketo from Salesforce, so I can use the Marketo API
3. syncLead makes an SOQL to Salesforce, and stores data for Lead01 as, for example, Map m
4. syncLead makes POST to create a new lead in Marketo using the information from Map m

Otherwise, is there another way to do this? Perhaps by linking to an external database through Salesforce?

Comment: yep - this should work except for a couple of issues - (1) the trigger needs to be bulkified to handle many leads in one transaction - this means that you need to work around governor issues on callouts; and 2) the trigger implicitly has the Lead data in trigger.new so no SOQL is required in step 3

Answer (score 0):

As per your above requirements:

- I think you should go for `workflow rules - Outbound Message` service of Salesforce. Send the outbound message to Marketo when ever new record is created for Lead Object or use a small php/java web application in between when ever outbound message is received to the mentioned integration endpoint in turn it create the new record in Marketo & send acknowledgement to Salesforce too.
  There is a [Integration & Data sync between Marketo and Salesforce](http://pages2.marketo.com/rs/marketob2/images/Marketo-and-SFDC-for-New-Customers.pdf.)
- Your own solution is also good.

Comment: your link goes to the Marketo home page; do you have a more specific link?